# Analytic function defined on unit disc with co-domain except negative real axis.

Tags: complex-analysis

I am trying to solve the following problem. Let $f$ be an analytic function defined on $\mathbb{D}=\{z:|z| <1 \}$ such that range of $f$ is contained in $\mathbb{C}$ \ $(-\infty,0]$.Then there exist an analytic function $g$ such that $Re g(z) \ge 0$ and $g$ is a square root of $f$ on $\mathbb{D}$ and there exist an analytic function $g$ such that $Re g(z) \le0$ and $g$ is a square root of $f$ on $\mathbb{D}$.  Clearly fuction $Log(f(z))$ and function $f(z)^{1/n} $are well defined according to given co-domain of $f$ . But these functions are not required function according to me. Then how to find required function $g$.
Since $f$ is non zero so $f^{'}/f$ is also analytic and there is a function $g$ such that $g=Log(f(z))$. Now i am stuck please some one help.

Comment: i think both branch of square root of f will work...

Comment: First you map the unit disk to the right-hand half-plane by a fractional-linear transformation. Then apply square root.

Comment: If possible please solve it completely....thanks in advance

Comment: My comment was completely wrong, sorry. I’ll also comment below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Clearly both branches of  $f(z)^{1/2}$  will form the required function $g.$

Comment: I disagree with these comments. Since $f$ maps into the slit disk (plane minus the nonpositive real axis), a domain on which the square root is well defined in such a way that $\sqrt1=1$, OP may indeed take the square root of $f$ to solve his problem.

Comment: Can you elaborate more on how both the branches of $f(z)^{\frac 12}$ form the required function $g$?